# Online training for Stanford NER

Tags: stanford-nlp

I understand that Stanford NER only supports training through a file... is there a way to *add more training data* at a later stage to *update* the NER model once it is already trained?

I understand that I can keep all the training datasets from the past and re-train the model, but, I am wondering if there is a way to *update* the NER model rather than *retrain* it from scratch.

Comment: Stanford NER doesn't support online training. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the larger audience: StanfordNER does not support Online Training. Marking this question as closed.